# Assignment and addition in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there an equivalent of the following in python?

```
ICMP_SEQUENCE_NUM   = self.sequence_num ++
```

That is, to do assign`ICMP_SEQUENCE_NUM = self.sequence_num`, and after that, increment `self.sequence_num` by one?

Comment: @flakes -- thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there is no way to perform a postfix or prefix operation directly, you can use the new walrus operator `:=` (assignment expression) to get close. This is only possible in Python >= 3.8:

```
# works
self.sequence_num = (ICMP_SEQUENCE_NUM := self.sequence_num) + 1
```

Note that you can't use the walrus operator on object attributes, so something like the following is not possible

```
# does not work
ICMP_SEQUENCE_NUM = (self.sequence_num := self.sequence_num + 1) - 1
```