# Why can I not assign to a named expression (LHS walrus operator)?

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-3.8, walrus-operator

Assigning to expressions (as opposed to names) is commonplace in Python.  For example, this is perfectly valid syntax:

```
my.object["with_some"].very_long["expression"] = func(my.object["with_some"].very_long["expression"], my.object["with_some"].very_long["expression"])
```

however, if I try to shorten it using the walrus operator by making the LHS a named expression such as

```
(x:=my.object["with_some"].very_long["expression"]) = func(x, x)
```

Python raises a SyntaxError:

> SyntaxError: cannot assign to named expression

Similarly, `for x[0] in range(5)` is valid syntax (just mightily confusing), whereas `for (a:=x[0]) in range(5)` is again a `SyntaxError: cannot assign to named expression`.

Why can't I assign to a named expression?  Is this by design or by implementation?

[PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#exceptional-cases) mentions some cases where the walrus operator cannot be used, but all but one are about the syntax of unparenthesised expressions and the final one is about f-strings.  Unlike the situation pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64055378/974555) (`(self.x := ...)`), the assignment target within the walrus operator in my case is a simple name/identifier, not an expression.  It's not clear from [the language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions) either why this is not allowed.  [Googling the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22syntaxerror%3A+cannot+assign+to+named+expression%22) today yields exactly three results at the time of writing: One [issue about limitations in comprehensions](https://bugs.python.org/issue38556), a [Stack Overflow chat message expecting hundreds of Hot Network Questions](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/6/2019/6/3) (which didn't happen), and [an issue in a 3rd-party Python parser](https://github.com/davidhalter/parso/issues/126); none help me.

What is the reason I cannot assign to a named expression?  Is this a design rule that is documented or defined somewhere, or is it an implementation limitation?  As far as I can see, it does not lead to any ambiguities and it would seem that my use case should be valid.

Comment: you could do this: `f(x:=..., x)`. but that does not answer the "Why can't I assign to a named expression?" part of your question.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist yes I could, I'd still have to repeat the long expression on both the left and the right side of the assignment operator though (just once rather than twice on the right side).

Comment: The value of a named expression is the *value* of the expression. A value isn't something you can assign to. What would you expect `(x := a+b) = f(x)` to mean?

Comment: @Barmer I'd expect `(x := a+b) = c` to fail with `cannot assign to operator`, like `a+b = c` does without named expressions.  Similarly, `for x[0] in range(5)` is valid syntax, `for (a:=x[0]) in range(5)` is `SyntaxError: cannot assign to named expression`.

Comment: @gerrit, please, see my expanded answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my.object["with_some"].very_long["expression"] = \
  func(my.object["with_some"].very_long["expression"],
       my.object["with_some"].very_long["expression"])`
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
my.object["with_some"].very_long.__setitem__(
    "expression",
    func(my.object["with_some"].very_long["expression"], 
         my.object["with_some"].very_long["expression"]))
```

so it's not as symmetrical as you think. The original long expression's *value*, not the expression itself, is passed as the two arguments to `func`, and the original expression itself is only *kind of* the target of an assignment.

You *could*, however, write

```
x["expression"] = func(
    (x:=my.object["with_some"].very_long)["expression"],
     x["expression"])
```

with `x` being assigned the value of the one common expression to the desugared version, `my.object["with_some"].very_long`.

The assignment expression has to be on the right-hand side of the assignment because that is evaluated before the left-hand side. Also, it has to be the *first* argument that uses `:=`, because function arguments are guaranteed to be evaluated from left to right.

---

Here's the test I used to verify that the above should work, assuming I defined `A` appropriately.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.b = dict(foo=y)


def func(x, y):
    return x + y


a = A(A("bar"))    
x["foo"] = func((x:=a.b["foo"].b)["foo"], x["foo"])
```

The new value of `a.b["foo"].b["foo"]` is `"barbar"`, as expected from the definition of `func`.

Answer (score 1):

The walrus operator assigns only as a **side effect** - its value is *not* the left-hand side variable, but the result of its right-hand side expression.

So the value of the named expression

```
(x:=my.object["with_some"].very_long["expression"])
```

is the *result of the right-hand side of the walrus operator* (`:=`), i. e. the result of the expression

```
my.object["with_some"].very_long["expression"]
```

Let's denote is as `result`, so your command

```
(x:=my.object["with_some"].very_long["expression"]) = func(x, x)
```

is the same as

```
result = func(x, x)
```

Now, `result` is a **value**, not a **variable name**. Maybe `None`, maybe a number, maybe a particular list or something else, but *not allowed in the left-hand side of the assignment operator.*

So, assigning to a named expression is (at least in most cases) meaningless, and for this reason not allowed.

Comment: But it's not the same, because the syntax isn't allowed. And you're no longer assigning the `x` variable that's used in the `func()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Compare:

```
my.object["with_some"].very_long["expression"] = func(7, 7)      # OK
```

with

```
7 = func(7, 7)                                                   # error
```

---

*The explanation:*

1. In your first expression

   ```
   my.object["with_some"].very_long["expression"] = \
       func(my.object["with_some"].very_long["expression"],               
             my.object["with_some"].very_long["expression"])
   ```

   you want to change the value of an **attribute** of your object (based on the value of its current attribute), i.e. to do something as

   ```
   my.object["with_some"].very_long["expression"] = func(7, 7)
   ```
2. In your second expression

   ```
   (x:=my.object["with_some"].very_long["expression"]) = func(x, x)
   ```

   the left-side hand of the assignment operator `(=)` is NOT an attribute of your object, but its **value.** So you tried assigning something to a *value*, i.e. to do something as

   ```
   7 = func(7, 7)
   ```

From [PEP 572 - Assignment Expressions, Abstract](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#abstract):

> This is a proposal for creating a way to assign to variables within an expression...

There is no mention of using it in the LHS of assignment.